# How to make this shawarma hot sauce?

Tags: sauce, restaurant-mimicry

I'm not sure how to ask this question so bear with me. This shawarma place nearby has this amazing hot sauce but I have no clue whats in it! I want to re-create it if possible. I talked to the clerk and he said that it may be BBQ sauce and hot sauce. I originally thought it tasted like ketchup and hot sauce.

Having said that any ideas of the recipe for this sauce?

[image]

Comment: Have you ever had [harissa](http://www.amazon.com/Cabanon-Harissa-Paste-tube-5-3/dp/B0050IKSBI/ref=sr_1_2?s=grocery&ie=UTF8&qid=1407483076&sr=1-2&keywords=harissa)? That is very likely to be the heat element of the sauce you're trying to duplicate (certainly the color seems right). Recipe requests are not allowed here, so I recommend that you try to make it and then if it doesn't seem right, tell us what you've tried and how the results differ from what you had at the restaurant. That way it could possibly be allowed as a "restaurant-mimicry" question.

Comment: As a first attempt I tried making this using ketchup and siracha sauce because that was all I had. I am going to try making this with a BBQ sauce and a hot sauce maybe I can find a similar taste.

Answer (score 3):

[Harissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harissa) Sauce is likely what you want, the sauce has found different names, it's origin includes Lebanon. 
I found one of many recipes at:
https://toriavey.com/toris-kitchen/harissa/

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the sauce is 'schaschlik sauce'.  It's a tomato-based sauce, with an interesting mix of spices.  You can find it in the US labeled as 'curry ketchup'.  There are a few companies that bottle it, and lots of variety -- there are some that are quite spicy (eg, the [Hela Extra Hot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JECX2AK).

If you search online, you can find recipes for it.  You can search for 'curry ketchup', but if you do, ignore the ones that call for curry powder + ketchup ... it's much more complex than that.

If you have any places near you that specialize in Dutch or German groceries, you might be able to find a place that imports the stuff at a more reasonable price than that Amazon link I had above.

(The last place I got the extra hot one was [Moore's Sauerkraut & Pickles](http://www.morsessauerkraut.com/) in Maine.  I've seen way more places with the 'scharf' (hot) or 'pikant' varieties ... skip the 'delikat' (mild) one)

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways of making hot sauce. First you need to be clear, was it salty or sweet?

1) Salty hot sauce: hot sauce, ketchup, cumin power, coriander powder, ginger/garlic paste,salt, pepper. (But your sauce doesn't look so spicy or thick)

2) Sweet hot sauce: hot sauce, bbq sauce, very little ranch, mustard sauce.